# How do I retrieve airflow url link to my latest task log in a DAG?

Tags: python, airflow

[image]

In individual DAG task, how do I set up the url link with the help from python operator as I am intending to send an url link of the latest log directly to the user whenever errors occur so that they can access to the page directly skipping the step of navigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `callback` function, which you can then pass to `DAG()` operator as default arugments.

```py
def on_failure_callback_slack(context):
    message = f"Failue! airflow task: {context['task_instance'].task_id} failed" \
f"dag: {base_url}?dag_id={context['dag'].dag_id} " \
f"{str(context['task_instance'])}"

    operator = PythonOperator(task_id="failure", python_callable=post_to_slack, op_kwargs={'message': message}
    
    return operator.execute(context=context)
```

In the above code, `post_to_slack()` is just a utility function to post to slack with `requests.post(...)`

You can pass this function to `DAG`, and it will post with the url to slack (or other medium of your choice). Note you will have to provide `base_url` for the url to work properly.

```py
default_args = {"on_failure_callback": on_failure_callback_slack}
dag=DAG(dag_id='some_id', default_args=default_args)
```

For more you can read here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. With some tweaks, managed to get the result!! Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Task instances have a `log_url` attribute. In the callback function, it can be accessed like so:

```py
def on_failure_callback(context):
    dag_run = context.get("dag_run")
    log_url = dag_run.get_task_instance({your_task_id}).log_url

    # Do whatever with the log_url
```

Depending on the Airflow setup, note that `log_url` might point to the local address (e.g. `http://localhost:8080`), which potentially should be replaced with whichever URL is being exposed to users.